# where to hash form data before saving the model in createview in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-validation

I am a little confused with where validation of form/model fields can happen in generic CreateView/UpdateView. Consider my hypothetical model below. I want the field `secret` to be hashed using my custom hashfunction and saved and assume some validation for `secret` field is done(NOT shown in the example below). My options to do this are:

1) in the model save method (I have not shown this below)

2) in the form's save method (I have shown below)

3) in the `form_valid` method of `AccountCreateView` (I have shown below)

4) how can I access the cleaned_data in the generic views (`cleaned_data` is available
only after `form_valid` is called)

Which is the right way to do it, both pros and cons. I will use the same form for `updateView`, in which case I will unhash the secret before displaying its data on the form. where this should happen?

**My model:**

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    secret = models.IntegerField()
```

**My form:**

```
AccountCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    secret = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = MediaContent
        exclude = (secret,user,created)

     def save(self, user, debate):
        obj = super(AccountCreateView, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.cleaned_data['user']
        obj.secret = myHashfunction(self.cleaned_data['secret'])
        obj.save()
```

**My view:**

```
class AccountCreateView(CreateView):
    """
    displays form to create a new search
    """
    model = Account
    form_class = AccountCreateForm

    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'app/account_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        secret=myHashfunction(self.request.POST['secret'])
        f.user = self.request.user
        f.save()
        return super(AccountCreateView,self).form_valid(form)
```

EDIT:

please see the edit to my model and form. the field I use in form is not the field in model.
It is a new Field, that takes CharField but the model  saves as IntegerField. my hashfunciton will convert the charField to IntegerField.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case `Form` is the better than `ModelForm`, as excluding every field on your model makes it redundant. You should then do any additional validation for the un-hashed `secret` here with `clean_secret`.

```
AccountCreateForm(forms.Form):
    secret=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now, if you are not using the `ModelForm` anymore, I would suggest using `FormView` over `CreateView` as the generic `CreateView` has become less of a good fit.

```
class AccountCreateView(FormView):
    """
    displays form to create a new search
    """
    form_class = AccountCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'app/account_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        unhashed_secret = form.cleaned_data['secret']
        hashed_secret = myHashfunction(unhashed_secret)
        user = self.request.user

        # Probably put some extra logic here to check if the user already exists
        Account.objects.create(
            user=user,
            secret=hashed_secret,
        )

        return super(AccountCreateView,self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: this is just a hypothetical model. Assume I have several other field related to model that is displayed in the form. but only `secret` is hashed. I kept the example above to drive the point.

Comment: OK, my answer is largely the same. The point is that you should put this logic in the `form_valid` method. I think that is the clearest place.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above. The correct place to do this is in the `clean_secret` method of the form. That is the place for any field-related validation and conversion. Simply return the hashed value from that method.

Comment: where do you perform the reverse conversion (unhashing in this example) to pre-fill the form for updateView?. I believe all the above should work. but might not be the right way?